# Purpose of a virtual path prefix in Express

Tags: express

The way to serve static on the server side seems pretty straightforward in Express:

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files,
>   use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.
>
> Pass the name of the directory that contains the static assets to the
>   express.static middleware function to start serving the files
>   directly. For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS
>   files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

> Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the
>   name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

To use multiple static assets directories, call the express.static
middleware function multiple times:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('files'))
```

Express looks up the files in the order in which you set the static directories with the express.static middleware function.

I get the idea of a virtual path prefix, but why would you use it?

> To create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually
>   exist in the file system) for files that are served by the
>   express.static function, specify a mount path for the static
>   directory, as shown below:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the /static path prefix.

```
http://localhost:3000/static/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/static/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/static/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/static/hello.html
```

Comment: How can this be done in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's a little late, but hope this could help you. BTW, I take no credit for the answer, just went to dive a little deeper on your concern and found this.

> This technique comes in handy when providing multiple directories to serve static files. The prefixes are used to help distinguish between the multiple directories.

If you would like to dig deeper. I found it on this link:
https://guide.freecodecamp.org/nodejs/express/